# Show all articles of a category in cms static block?

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to load all products of a category in a CMS static block?

Maybe there is a CMS Block which I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible

1. You should create your cms block with content

   {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="custom.catalog.product.list"  category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

put in category_id="" your category id

2. then you should go to System > Configuration > Permissions > Blocks > Add New Block

   Block Name: catalog/product_list

   Is Allowed: Yes
3. clear cache

Comment: @Serhil, thank you very much, that worked like a charm :)